# How do I center content next to a floated element and relative to the containing element?

Tags: css, css-float, center

I have markup that looks like this

```
<div>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;" >Heading 1</h1>
  <img style="float:left;" src="logo.gif"/>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;" >Heading 2</h1>
</div>
<div>
  Content goes here
</div>
```

The problem is that heading 2 is centered relative to the remainder of space after the image, and not to the whole div, so its not centered on the page.

If I remove the img from the flow with position:absolute, it does not push down the content and instead overlaps it.

Comment: Two comments in general: 1) It is considered better practice to specify styles in your CSS file instead of inline; 2) There is a separate site http://doctype.com/ for questions related to web programming where you might get better response.

Comment: This isn't production code, its as concise an example as possible of the problem.

Comment: Kudos to that, the conciseness of the question made me vote it up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it through trial and error.  I don't know why but in my testing it only works if width is set between 12 and 80%.

So it seems "h1" is a block element, and text-align does not center block elements, it only centers inline elements inside it, which explains the "centered off-center" behavior.  So it turns out the answer is the same answer to the question "how do you center a block element?"

```
<div>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Heading 1</h1>
    <img style="float:left;" src="logo.gif"/>
    <h1 style=" 
             text-align:center;
             margin-left:auto;
             margin-right:auto;
             width:50%;
      ">Heading 2</h1>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
  Content goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a right padding to the div with the size of the logo:

```
<div style="padding-right: 50px;">
  <img style="float:left;" src="logo.gif"/>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;" >Heading</h1>
</div>
<div>
  Content goes here
</div>
```

Another way is to remove the heading from the flow. This only works on the assumption that the logo height is bigger than the heading height. Beware also that image and heading could overlap.

```
 <h1 style="position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align:center;">
    Heading
</h1>
<img style="float:left;" src="logo.gif"/>
<div style="clear:both;">
  Content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Position relative does not remove the element from the flow. The second example does not center the text.

Comment: @Matt: Relative doesn't, but absolute would. Is there any reason you can't absolutely position your image? Even if you don't want the image absolutely positioned relative to the page, you can still contain it inside a `<div>` that's positioned relatively, so the image would be positioned relative to the `<div>` rather than the document body.

Comment: @Matt: You are right about the first example, corrected it to `position: absolute`. The second example would center the text if you add a `width: 100%` to the nested `DIV`?

Comment: @littlegreen:  The absolute doesnt work, I edited my question to show why.  float:left and width:100% cancel eachother out and the div goes below the img.

Comment: You are right, and the second solution was also not correct. I changed them both and tested them, should work now.

Comment: The first solution only works when you know the dimensions of the img and can hard code it.  The second one _almost_ gets it, its very close, but not truly centered.  You can verify this is in firebug by toggling the position:absolute property on and off.  When its off, the heading is exactly centered, but above the img

Answer (score 1):

I know i am late for the party, but for future readers I found a different approach for that problem.
use 3 div elements (left div,middle div, right div) inside a flex displayed div container.

make the left and right div the same relative width (in %) and float each one of the to his side.
set the middle div width with reminder of  100% - (left div + right div).
locate the image in the left div (or right div if your direction is RTL).
set the text align of the middle div as 'center'.
check this example. also here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/c0Ph6Xq7ZCehRTaZJuFG?p=preview) .

[image]

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>

#editorheader {
  display:flex;
}

#leftheaderdiv {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:gray;
    display:inline-block;
}
#middleheaderdiv {
float:left;
    width:60%;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#rightheaderdiv {
    float:right;
    width:20%;
    background-color: gray;
}

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div class="subheader" id="editorheader">
       <div id="leftheaderdiv"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d"/></div>
       <div id="middleheaderdiv">I AM IN THE MIDDLE</div>
       <div id="rightheaderdiv"></div>
   </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really using logo image then you might try this solution:

```
<div> 
  <img style="float:left;" src="logo.jpg"/> 
  <h1 style="text-align:center; position:relative; left:-100px;" >Heading</h1> 
</div>
```

where -100px replace with half of yours image width.

**edit:**

idea with absolute position from littlegreen's answer is working. Check it:

```
<div style="position:relative;"> 
  <img style="float:left; position:absolute;" src="logo.jpg"/> 
  <h1 style="text-align:center;" >Heading</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Its a dynamic page, so I don't know what the image will be.  I suppose I could use javascript to get the width and then set it, but I want to believe there is a way to do this in just css.

Comment: This does answer the question as I originally asked it, but when you add content after this, the img falls down on top of it

Answer (score 0):

This most simple solution:

`<h2 style="text-align:center;text-indent:-*px">Heading 2</h2>`

- = the logo width